# expo static server - how to host a file and get url on local server

Tags: mobile, expo, localhost, hosting

in duofolio, https://github.com/farshed/duofolio/blob/master/src/screens/EpubReader.js
we create a static local server to host and later get the file using http.

let newServer = new StaticServer(0, ExternalStorageDirectoryPath, serverConfig);

is there something similar in expo?
some small local server that i can "host" a file at ?

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

Hello, as of 2023, you can use the library `@dr.pogodin/react-native-static-server` with Expo as long as you use a development build (running expo prebuild and exposing /ios and /android folders). This library is a fork from the main react-native-static-server that is being maintained still.

#### 1. Development build

In your Managed Expo project, run `npx expo prebuild --clean` to regenerate the /ios and /android directories based on the Expo config (app.json) configuration, check more [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/adopting-prebuild/#prebuild).

For more info about generating the development build (APK to test instead of using Expo Go App), please check Expo's [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/).

#### 2. Static server library

Now with the ios and android folders exposed, you can edit then manually like in a normal React Native app. Now you need to follow `@dr.pogodin/react-native-static-server` [documentation](https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-static-server) and don't forget to add the items mentioned in the section "Bundling-in Server Assets Into an App Statically" for iOS and Android.

#### 3. React Native file system

It's also mandatory to add the library `react-native-fs`, so you have to do an extra configuration inside /ios and /android folders and run `pod install` for iOS. Check more [here](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

#### 4. Pre Install Hook

If you're building the app with EAS Build, you have to create a pre-install hook to install CMake.

This is how I did:

1. First you add a script to package.json:
   `"eas-build-pre-install": "./pre-install",`
2. Then you add the `pre-install` script file to your root folder:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script will follow the script eas-build-pre-install located in package.json and will be executed before EAS Build runs npm install on the EAS Build platform.
echo "running pre install..."

if [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "android" ]]; then
  sudo apt-get install --yes cmake
elif [[ "$EAS_BUILD_PLATFORM" == "ios" ]]; then
  HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install cmake
fi
```

This will run an extra step that will ensure that CMake is inside the machine that will then build the app (while using EAS Build).

### 5. Usage

You can follow their [example](https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-static-server/blob/master/example/src/App.tsx) or create your own solution.
In my case I created a hook so I can call from any other component and host multiple websites:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import Server, {
  extractBundledAssets,
  getActiveServer,
  STATES,
} from '@dr.pogodin/react-native-static-server';

import { ServerContextData, ServerProviderProps } from './types';

const ServerContext = React.createContext<ServerContextData>({} as ServerContextData);

const ServerProvider = ({ children }: ServerProviderProps) => {
  const serverRef = React.useRef<Server | null>();
  const [origin, setOrigin] = React.useState<string>('');

  const extractFiles = React.useCallback(async (fileDir: string, gameId: string) => {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'android') return;

    let extract = true;

    try {
      const versionD = await RNFS.readFile(`${fileDir}/version`, 'utf8');
      const versionA = await RNFS.readFileAssets('webroot/version', 'utf8');

      if (versionA === versionD) {
        extract = false;
      } else {
        await RNFS.unlink(fileDir);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'extractFiles');
    }

    if (extract) {
      console.log('Extracting web server assets...');
      await extractBundledAssets(fileDir, `webroot/${gameId}`);
    }
  }, []);

  const stopServer = React.useCallback(async () => {
    if (!serverRef.current) return;

    await serverRef.current?.stop();

    serverRef.current = null;
    setOrigin('');
  }, []);

  const startServer = React.useCallback(
    async (gameId: string) => {
      const activeServer = getActiveServer();

      console.log('active', activeServer);
      console.log('serverRef', serverRef.current?.state, serverRef.current?.id);

      if (activeServer || serverRef.current?.state === STATES.ACTIVE) {
        await stopServer();
      }

      const fileDir: string = Platform.select({
        android: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/webroot/${gameId}`,
        ios: `${RNFS.MainBundlePath}/webroot/${gameId}`,
        windows: `${RNFS.MainBundlePath}\\webroot/${gameId}`,
        default: '',
      });

      serverRef.current = new Server({ fileDir, stopInBackground: true });
      const serverId = serverRef.current.id;

      await extractFiles(fileDir, gameId);

      serverRef.current?.addStateListener((newState, details, error) => {
        console.log(
          `Server #${serverId}.\n`,
          `New state: "${STATES[newState]}".\n`,
          `Details: "${details}".`
        );
        if (error) console.error(error);
      });

      const res = await serverRef.current?.start();
      if (res && serverRef.current) {
        setOrigin(res);
      }
    },
    [stopServer, extractFiles]
  );

  const value: ServerContextData = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ origin, startServer, stopServer }),
    [origin, startServer, stopServer]
  );

  return <ServerContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ServerContext.Provider>;
};

const useServer = (): ServerContextData => {
  const context = React.useContext(ServerContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useServer must be within a ServerProvider');
  }

  return context;
};

export { ServerProvider, useServer };
```

Then you import the `ServerProvider` and wrapp it in your app:

```js
<ServerProvider> {children} </ServerProvider>
```

And to use the hook, just call from your component that has the webview so you can load the content:

```js
import { useServer } from 'hooks';
import * as React from 'react';

import { SafeAreaView, View } from 'react-native';

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

import { styles } from './styles';

export const TestScreen = () => {
  const { origin, startServer, stopServer } = useServer();
  const webView = React.useRef<WebView>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    startServer('test');

    return () => {
      stopServer();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.webview}>
        {origin && <WebView ref={webView} originWhitelist={['*']} source={{ uri: origin }} />}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

I guess that's it. For me the server is working fine. Remember that only one instance of the server can be loaded at a time.

Please not that in my case, I have subfolders inside the `webroot` folder with one site for each so I can load them depending on the gameId I pass to the `startServer` function.